# Netty, how to store data through all handlers

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety, netty

Im new to Netty and I have a question about storing the data received by clients in the server, for a later consult by whatever clients.

If I define the pipeline as follow:

```
ch.pipeline().addLast(new ServerHandler());
```

Can i define in my ServerHandler a class variable as follow ?

```
public class ServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

private static final ArrayList<String> llamadas = new ArrayList<String>();
....
```

And after use it whitin all clients like this ?

```
synchronized(llamadas) {
            llamadas.add(mensaje);
}
```

Also I want to ask if there is any difference if I create only one instance of ServerHandler

```
ch.pipeline().addLast(serverHandler);
```

and I annotate the class with @Sharable

make any difference in the access of the variable?

Many thanks!!

regards.

Comment: Just a quick note that `@Sharable` doesn't do anything on its own, it's merely there fore documentation.

Comment: Thanks,  I know, but as Long as you declare the class sharable it is supousse you are going to have only one instance of your handler and thats mean that object is going to be shared for all threads, in that case It seems possible to make an instance variable (non static) and use it in a synchronized block . On the other hand , if we create one instance per channel in the pipeline it is neccesary to create a class variable (static variable) and again use it in a synchronized block, is this correct? Or am i missing something?

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a Java question than Netty-specific. Since `llamadas` is a static class member, you will need to synchronize regardless of whether you make your ChannelHandler `@Sharable` or not i.e whether you have multiple instances of the channel handler or only one, you have a single `ArrayList` you are appending to.

Generally, `@Sharable` is used with handlers that are "stateless" w.r.t channels i.e that do not maintain any channel-specific state, and so you can get away with using a single instance of the handler across pipelines.
See this [tutorial](http://seeallhearall.blogspot.com/2012/06/netty-tutorial-part-15-on-channel.html) for a good explanation of this.

Comment: Thanks for the response, so in the case i dont need to store channel specific state i should use sharable and a single instance of the handler to save resources and i guess the shared variable could be non static.